# Laravel Nginx 403 forbidden

Tags: laravel, nginx, http-status-code-403

In my `public` directory i have a folder called `users`. Also in  my rotes I have defined 'users' route. So when I am trying to visit `/users` I am getting an error 403 forbidden.

Comment: have you default.conf?

Comment: Yes, because the existence of a folder in `public` will ensure that any request for that will always be handled by nginx before PHP is even touched. You cannot have both of these things.